# Sales Order History table

Tags: myob

This might be a long shot, but I'm attempting to get a copy of MYOB's order history page that I can link to on our company website so customer's can see the progress of their order.

I've been brought on to help update a ten year old website, and I can't tell how much of the SQL backend is MYOB and how much has been added in around it, the site is fairly small but has more than 300 SQL tables behind it all with very similar names.

I can't find anything about it on the MYOB support site. I'm hoping that it's a generic MYOB table and not something custom the last developer has rigged up.

[image: This is what I'm trying to find in SQL]

Any help would be much appreciated. Even if it's just an idea of a table to start looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, it looks like you've got MYOB EXO Business. Your options depend upon which version you're using. If you've got v8.3+ there is a RESTful API with documentation here: http://developer.myob.com/api/exo/. For earlier versions you have no choice but to talk directly to the database. A v8.8 schema is published here: http://help.myob.com.au/exo/schemas/exo88/index.htm. I realise this may not be for the version you are working with but it looks like what you need is in the Sales table (shown on the Business Core - Debtors diagram). Good luck!

Comment: Looking at the table schema, I think you're on to a winner. I'll have to rig up a page myself (I was hoping to find a ready made template... oh well, guess I should do my job) but all the information looks to be on one table for a change. Thanks.